# My content is floating beind container in media query

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a burger menu and when i do, my `.nav-list` goes behind the container when i give a `float: none;`

I tried giving it `margin: 0;` and everything but nothing seems to work. I am trying to get it to open up and decrease the height of the container and when closed, increase the height of the container and decrease the height of the menu bar.

Here is my code and the rest is in this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBBdWv

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jobs-popup">

    <img id="x-icon1" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">

    <div class="jobs-content">
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
<!--End Section for Jobs Popup -->

<!-- Section for contact popup -->
<div id="contact-popup">

    <img id="x-icon2" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">

    <div id="contact-content">
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
<!-- End Section for Contact Popup -->

<!-- Section for Press popup -->
<div id="press-popup">

    <img id="x-icon3" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">

    <div id="press-content">
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
<!-- End section Press -->

<!-- Section for legal popup -->
<div id="legal-popup">

    <img id="x-icon4" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">

    <div id="legal-content">
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        ...
    </div>

</div>
<!-- End section Legal -->

<!-- Section for Support -->
<div id="support-popup">

    <img id="x-icon5" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">

    <div id="support-content">
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
        ...
    </div>

</div>

<center>

    <div id="top-bar">

        <a class="burger-nav"></a>

        <div id="nav-bar">

            <ul>
                <a href="#" id="jobs" class="test">
                    <li class="nav-list" id="job-under">Jobs</li>
                </a>

                <a href="#" id="contact" class="test">
                    <li class="nav-list" id="contact-under">Contact</li>
                </a>

                <a href="#" id="press" class="test">
                    <li class="nav-list" id="press-under">Press</li>
                </a>

                <a href="#" id="legal" class="test">
                    <li class="nav-list" id="legal-under">Legal</li>
                </a>

                <a href="#" id="support" class="test">
                    <li class="nav-list" id="support-under">Support</li>
                </a>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <ul id="menu"></ul>

        <h1 id="name">Touch</h1>

        <ul class="bubbles">

            <li id="firstCircle"></li>
            <li id="secondCircle"></li>
            <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
            <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
            <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
            <li id="sixthCircle"></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</center>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid. You shouldn't use `center` and in `.nav-list` you have `div > ul > a > li`. An `a` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. You need to swap the `a` and `li` so that it's `div > ul > li > a`

Comment: where do you see this?

Comment: Search for "center" in your code, and if you read my comment, it says "in `.nav-list` you have `div > ul > a > li`".... so, in `.nav-list`.

Comment: i did that, but still the words are going behind the container.

Comment: Fix the markup errors in your codepen and in the post please.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBBdWv

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XMMGRM?editors=1100 btw you have `href` attributes in your `li`'s now.

Comment: Yes how did you do that? and how do you remove the margin or padding on the left of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `position` and `z-index` values on all of those popup elements at the beginning of your code, and they are overlaying on top of `#top-bar` in your media query layout. To put `#top-bar` on top of them, give it a non-static `position` and a `z-index` higher than the popups. I used `#top-bar { position: relative; z-index: 101; }`

And to get rid of the default `padding-left` on the `ul` in `#top-bar` apply `padding: 0;`.

And btw, you have `href` attributes in the `li`'s in `#top-bar`. You can fix that though.

```css
 #top-bar {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 7%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 101;
 }

#top-bar ul {
  padding: 0;
}
 
 #container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   color: #262626;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 ul {
   list-style: none;
   top: 9%;
 }
 
 .nav-list {
   float: left;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   padding-right: 1%;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 2%;
 }
 /*Reg bubbles section -------------------------------------------- */
 
 .bubbles {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 0;
   transform: translateZ(0);
 }
 
 .bubbles li {
   position: absolute;
   list-style: none;
   display: block;
   border-radius: 100%;
   -ms-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
   -webkit-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
   -moz-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
   -o-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
 }
 /* The first Circle animation------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   top: 20%;
   left: 20%;
   background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fad0c4 99%, #fad0c4 100%);
   animation-name: firstCircle;
 }
 /* Mozilla First Circle Animation */
 
 @-moz-keyframes firstCircle {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Webkit First Circle Animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes firstCircle {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 
 @-ms-keyframes firstCircle {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* End first circle animation -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /* Begin Second Circle Animation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 40%;
   animation-name: secondAnimation;
 }
 /* Webkit Second Animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes secondAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Mozilla Second Animation */
 
 @-moz-keyframes secondAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Ms Second Animation */
 
 @-ms-keyframes secondAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* End of Second Circle ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /*Begin of Third Circle ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 60%;
   top: 10%;
   animation-name: thirdAnimation;
 }
 /* Webkit Third Animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes thirdAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Mozilla Third Animation */
 
 @-moz-keyframes thirdAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* MS Third Animation */
 
 @-ms-keyframes thirdAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* End of the Third Circle --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /* Begin of Fourth Circle Animation ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 60%;
   animation-name: fourthAnimation;
 }
 /* Webkit Fourth Animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes fourthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Mozilla Fourth Animation */
 
 @-moz-keyframes fourthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* MS Fourth Animation */
 
 @-ms-keyframes fourthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* END of Fourth Animation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
 /* Start of Fifth Animation -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 10%;
   animation-name: fifthAnimation;
 }
 /* Webki Fifth Animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes fifthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 
 @-moz-keyframes fifthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 
 @-ms-keyframes fifthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* End of the Fith Circle ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /* Start of the Sixth Circle ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 .bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
   width: 9%;
   height: 20%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 80%;
   top: 60%;
   animation-name: sixthAnimation;
 }
 /* Webkit sixth animation */
 
 @-webkit-keyframes sixthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* Mozilla Sixth Animation */
 
 @-moz-keyframes sixthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* MS Sixth Animation */
 
 @-ms-keyframes sixthAnimation {
   0% {
     z-index: 100;
     -ms-transform: scale(0);
   }
   100% {
     z-index: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(200);
   }
 }
 /* End of Sixth Animation ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 
 #name {
   color: white;
   font-size: 6em;
   position: relative;
   top: 30%;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
   z-index: 10;
 }
 
 #jobs li {
   color: #262626;
 }
 
 #contact li {
   color: #262626;
 }
 
 #press li {
   color: #262626;
 }
 
 #legal li {
   color: #262626;
 }
 
 #support li {
   color: #262626;
 }
 
 #jobs-popup {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-top: 5%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 
 .jobs-content {
   width: 600px;
   height: 560px;
   margin: 20 auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #x-icon1 {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 4%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
 }
 
 .whip {
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: black;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #contact-popup {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-top: 5%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 
 #contact-content {
   width: 600px;
   height: 560px;
   margin: 20 auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #x-icon2 {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 4%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #press-popup {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-top: 5%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 
 #press-content {
   width: 600px;
   height: 560px;
   margin: 20 auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #x-icon3 {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 4%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #legal-popup {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-top: 5%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 
 #legal-content {
   width: 600px;
   height: 560px;
   margin: 20 auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #x-icon4 {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 4%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #support-popup {
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   margin-top: 5%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 
 #support-content {
   width: 600px;
   height: 560px;
   margin: 20 auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: white;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
 }
 
 #x-icon5 {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10%;
   top: 4%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .bubbles {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 415px) {
   #name {
     margin-top: 20%;
     font-size: 4em;
   }
   .burger-nav {
     display: block;
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;
     background: url(Pictures/burgerlogo.png) no-repeat 98% center;
     background-size: 30px 30px;
     background-color: #404040;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   #top-bar ul {
     height: 40%;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #505050;
     //height: 0;
   }
   #top-bar ul.open {
     height: auto;
   }
   ul {
     margin-top: 0;
   }
   .nav-list {
     float: none;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div id="jobs-popup">
  <img id="x-icon1" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div class="jobs-content">
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>

  </div>

</div>
<!--End Section for Jobs Popup -->

<!-- Section for contact popup -->
<div id="contact-popup">
  <img id="x-icon2" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="contact-content">
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>

  </div>


</div>
<!-- End Section for Contact Popup -->

<!-- Section for Press popup -->
<div id="press-popup">
  <img id="x-icon3" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="press-content">
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- End section Press -->

<!-- Section for legal popup -->
<div id="legal-popup">
  <img id="x-icon4" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="legal-content">
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- End section Legal -->
<!-- Section for Support -->
<div id="support-popup">
  <img id="x-icon5" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png">
  <div id="support-content">
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>
    <h1 class="whip">Test</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="top-bar">
  <a class="burger-nav"></a>
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li href="#" id="jobs" class="test"><a class="nav-list" id="job-under">Jobs</a></li>
      <li href="#" id="contact" class="test"><a class="nav-list" id="contact-under">Contact</a></li>
      <li href="#" id="press" class="test"><a class="nav-list" id="press-under">Press</a></li>
      <li href="#" id="legal" class="test"><a class="nav-list" id="legal-under">Legal</a></li>
      <li href="#" id="support" class="test"><a class="nav-list" id="support-under">Support</a></li>


    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="container">

  <ul id="menu">


  </ul>

  <h1 id="name">Touch</h1>
  <ul class="bubbles">

    <li id="firstCircle"></li>
    <li id="secondCircle"></li>
    <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
    <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
    <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
    <li id="sixthCircle"></li>


  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much